# Broadcast Receiver doesnt work statically

Tags: java, android

I want to notify when power of the phone connects and disconnects by broadcast receiver.
but the problem is that it doesnt work when i define receiver in manifest, but it works well if i defineit dynamically.
This is my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.batterymanager">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my Broadcast:

```
package com.example.batterymanager;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /*if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Power Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED")){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Power Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/

        Toast.makeText(context, "" + intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("HUU", intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

I dont know why it doesnt work! ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New android limitations:

> As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits,
>   apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register
>   broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.
>   However, several broadcasts are currently exempted from these
>   limitations. Apps can continue to register listeners for the following
>   broadcasts, no matter what API level the apps target.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions